# Active Directory Error in findUser function

Tags: node.js, active-directory

I have the following code in my javascript:

```
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(adConfig);
        ad.authenticate(username, password, function (err, auth) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("ERROR : " + JSON.stringify(err));
                res.send(false);
                return;
            }
            if (auth) {
                console.log("User " + username.split('\\')[1] + " authenticated");
                ad.findUser(username.split('\\')[1], function (err, user) {
                    //More code here
                }
```

My program reaches to the ad.findUser line, but there, I get the following error:

> activedirectory.js:416
> delete result.controls; // Remove the controls array returned as part of the SearchEntry
> ^
> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Line 416 of file activedirectory.js is the one that starts with 'delete' here:

```
function onSearchEntry(entry) {
    log.trace('onSearchEntry(%j)', entry);
    console.log('entry', entry);
    var result = entry.object;
    delete result.controls; // Remove the controls array returned as part of the SearchEntry
    ...
```

My 'entry' object is of type `SearchResultEntry [LdapMessage] {...}`, which effectivement does not have a 'object' attribute, so 'result' is undefined. That's why my code is not working. However, I do not understand why I arrive to that situation.

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/issues/246), it seems like the activedirectory library doesn't work with ldapjs 3.0.0, so you may need to add an override in your package.json:

```
"overrides": {
  "activedirectory": {
    "ldapjs": "2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: It works well when I override the ldapjs version, thanks!